# Is there a Rake task for FTP?

Tags: ruby, rake

I'm looking for a Rake task to do deployment via FTP.

Does anyone know of any?

Anders

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I decided to do it myself. The code is not very beautiful since it contains a lot of exception handling, but it gets the job done :)

```
require 'rake'
require 'net/ftp'

def ftp_files(prefixToRemove, sourceFileList, targetDir, hostname, username, password)
  Net::FTP.open(hostname, username, password) do |ftp|
  begin
    puts "Creating dir #{targetDir}" 
    ftp.mkdir targetDir
  rescue 
    puts $!
  end
  sourceFileList.each do |srcFile|    
    if prefixToRemove
      targetFile = srcFile.pathmap(("%{^#{prefixToRemove},#{targetDir}}p")) 
    else
      targetFile = srcFile.pathmap("#{targetDir}%s%p")
    end
    begin
      puts "Creating dir #{targetFile}" if File.directory?(srcFile)
      ftp.mkdir targetFile if File.directory?(srcFile)
    rescue 
      puts $!
    end
    begin
      puts "Copying #{srcFile} -> #{targetFile}" unless File.directory?(srcFile)
      ftp.putbinaryfile(srcFile, targetFile) unless File.directory?(srcFile)
    rescue 
      puts $!
    end
  end
  end
end

task :ftp => [:dist] do
  ftp_files("dist", FileList["dist/**/*"], "remote_dir", 'host.com', 'user', 'pwd')
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Not that I know of though the [Net::SFTP](http://net-ssh.rubyforge.org/sftp/v2/api/) gem is pretty nice, you can write a [new rake task](http://railscasts.com/episodes/66) pretty easily to do what you would like.

It also depends on what kind of deployment you're doing - if its Rails, have you looked into [Capistrano](http://www.capify.org/) or [Vlad the Deployer](http://rubyhitsquad.com/Vlad_the_Deployer.html)?

Answer (score 2):

Above code didn't work for me.
I created different one:
https://gist.github.com/1690647